# Android AnimationDrawable?

Tags: android

I want to create a dynamic image of a glass of water where the amount of water in the glass changes based on back-end variables. I was wondering how would I go about accomplishing this? Do I need to create the images in Illustrator and use AnimationDrawable or should I use something else?

Comment: you need to post at least a piece os code here... Stackoverflow is not working so......

Comment: I imagine the answer will involve creating a custom `View` class, and drawing a line within a glass shape with a variable `y` value that corresponds to your data - please add any code you have so far, and/or an image of the effect you'd like to achieve.

Comment: Well I don't have any code for it yet because I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing it. I want to do something like this http://www.quartzcodeapp.com/tutorial-water-fill-animation-using-quartzcode/ but in android.